# Run registry issue. DELETE script opening folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created two scripts, one to delete shortcuts from a folder whenever the system boots up using Run registry and the other to add REG key to Run registry. **The problem is whenever I bootup my device it keeps opening the folder location specified in the DELETE Script.** Any solution for this guys ? I will share the commands that I used below.

DELETE script :

```
del /s /q "%Appdata%/Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\*.*"
```

ADDING REG KEY TO RUN script :

```
xcopy /s "%~dp0delete.bat" "C:\Program Files\perma\"

REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Delete /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\perma\delete.bat" /f
```

Comment: I do not know what causes your problem, I cannot reproduce it (by opening the folder location you mean an Explorer window, right?), but there are a few minor issues: 1. you used a wrong path separator `/` instead of `\ `behind `%AppData%`; 2. `xcopy /S` does not make sense for copying a single file, better use `copy` instead; 3. you specify the value type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, so you should perhaps use the value `%ProgramFiles%\perma\delete.bat`…

Comment: To begin with, please try to explain the purpose of using a REG_EXPAND_SZ data type? Then if you really feel that it is still necessary, provide an expandable string to it, because currently you have not! `REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Delete /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%ProgramFiles%%\perma\delete.bat" /f`. I would advise that you just use a regular string instead, `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /V Delete /T REG_SZ /D "\"%ProgramFiles%\perma\delete.bat\"" /F 1>NUL`